# Matplotlib: Displaying and closing a plot using a loop

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, psychopy

Using Matplotlib and a for loop, is it possible to display a plot for a given period of time and then have it close when the for loop is done?

I have tried the following, but the plot simply remains open and the loop doesn't end:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import psychopy

x = [34.00,108.00,64.00,99.00,99.00,51.00]
y = [5.00,17.00,11.00,8.00,14.00,5.00]

scatter(x, y, color = "black")

clock = core.Clock()

while clock.getTime() < 10.0:
    plt.show()

plt.close()
```

Thanks

Comment: you only need to call `show` once, use `time.sleep` then `close`

Comment: I tried (plt.show() .. time.sleep(3) .. plt.close()) but the plot just hangs open and the code doesn't move on.

Comment: in either case, you only need `show` once, so take it out of the loop

Comment: I did, that doesn't solve the problem though

Comment: I know, but it's a first step

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use interactive mode `plt.ion()` in combination with `plt.pause()`.

E.g. to show your window for 5 seconds:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [34.00,108.00,64.00,99.00,99.00,51.00]
y = [5.00,17.00,11.00,8.00,14.00,5.00]

plt.scatter(x, y, color = "black")
plt.ion()
plt.draw()
plt.pause(5)
```